# What makes enterprise beans 'heavyweight'?

Tags: ejb, javabeans, java-ee-6

I have read numerous times that EJBs are heavyweight...yet last night I was going through the Java EE 6 tutorials on EJBs and they seem to be just regular Java objects, except they can have annotations like Stateless or Singletons. Other than that the functionality they contained in the (admittedly very basic) tutorials was very standard, just like a model class in an MVC application.

1. So why have come across very negative attitudes to EJBs?
2. Why I have seen it said that they are unnecessary for the vast majority of web apps?
3. And what makes them 'heavyweight'?

Comment: EJBs add many benefits to enterprise applications including transactions, messaging, RPC, etc.  The additional design, coding, and app server needs to support them could be considered "heavyweight", plus if you do not select the proper type of EJB it could cripple your performance.  For example, an Entity EJB is often the cause of performance meltdowns where a Stateless Session EJB could have sufficed.  EJBs require a "lookup" and instantiation and remote clients require a client library and typically a J2EE app server like JBoss, WebLogic, WebSphere.  JBoss is open source but latter 2 $$$.

Comment: -1 If your sources cannot provide any of those points, then maybe they are not very good. Also EJB has a long history EJB 3.1 as you see in Java EE6 is nothing like what you might have seen in 2004. I suggest you check the dates on your sources as well. Also this question is highly subjective and very open.

Comment: @MikeS EJB Entity Beans (not to be confused with JPA entities!) are completely deprecated and thus rarely used. EJBs don't require a lookup but can be easily injected. What on earth is a J2EE app server??? Did you just arrived with a time capsule from 2004???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few causes of EJB beans being heavyweight.

The first one is Rod Johnson's rhetoric. For people to adopt Spring it was important for Rod to spread the idea that EJB is heavyweight (and Spring thus automatically lightweight). Springsource is a commercial organization and Rod a clever businessman. The more people use Spring, the bigger the percentage of them that will eventually buy a support contract from SpringSource.

The second source are Spring zealots who never tried EJB, but always heard from Rod and other zealots that EJB is heavyweight. They are simply parotting the song they've heard.

The third source are people burned by EJB 2 in 2004 and before. This version of EJB was indeed heavyweight. People turned their back to EJB back then, never looked back and are completely oblivious that EJB 3 happened, which is as you have observed a very lightweight and easy to use technology.